# Ruby in Aptana: Cannot Start Debugger

Tags: ruby, rubygems, aptana, ruby-debug

When I try to start debugging in Aptana Studio 3, an error occurs:

```
/Users/shia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'ruby-debug-ide' (>= 0) among 7 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/shia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/shia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /Users/shia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/rdebug-ide:22
```

After a while a dialog pops out saying "An internal error occurred during: "Launching Game.rb". Could not connect to debugger on port 54008". (*Game.rb* is the file that I'm debugging.)

I'm using Ruby on OS X 10.9.1. I first installed the latest version, Ruby 2.0.0, using Homebrew. Then I found out the debugger doesn't work well with Ruby 1.9+, so I installed RVM and used it to install Ruby 1.8.7. Then I executed `$rvm use 1.8.7` in the Terminal.

After that, I executed `$gem install ruby-debug-ide` and `$gem install ruby-debug-base` and everything looked OK. But when I restarted Aptana, the debugging still didn't work and returned the error above.

Not sure which step I'm missing here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, set the defualt ruby and gem set version for rvm.

```
rvm --default use 'ruby-2.1.1@global' 
rvm --default use 'ruby-2.1.1'
```